# Python Socket.io client halts with message "Received unexpected packet of type 1"

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi

My goals is to have real-time communication between a number of raspberry pi's over a server. I need the server for live access to logging.

I'm using the python Socket.io library from [here](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html) to connect to a NodeJS Express/socket.io server. Eventually I intend to run the NodeJS server on an actual server, but I'm currently running the server and client on one raspberry pi 3.

I've managed to get the communication going in both directions, but after a few minutes of inactivity (doesn't happen when there is data flowing), the python script will log "Received unexpected packet of type 1" and completely stop working. I've tested the connection with a regular html/js client, where this did not happen.

I'm also using the background task function provided by the python socket.io library to listen for button presses through the Pi's GPIO pins.

Any idea what may be causing the process to stop? The 'disconnect' event does not fire. I've been googling the message, but haven't found anything so far, but I'm also new to Python...

I think it has to do with the multiple processes? When I comment out the start_background_task(buttons) line, this doesn't seem to happen.

Thanks!! I can't find too much more about SocketIO on client side python...

**app.js (nodeJS)**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');
    client.on('button', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
});

server.listen(4200);
```

**client.py**

```
import socketio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Use physical pin numbering
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('connected to server')

@sio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('disconnected from server')

def buttons():
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(10) == GPIO.HIGH:
            print("Button was pushed!")
            sio.emit('button', {"pi":1, "button": 1})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.connect('http://localhost:4200')
    sio.start_background_task(buttons)
```

EDIT: fixed duplicate function names. No change in outcome.

Comment: How come 2 functions with same name `on_connect`?

Comment: @Paandittya, right, well spotted. Do you think that may be it? Trying it now. (Was also trying out with the sio.connect() line commented out, which also seemed to keep going... )
UPDATE: receiving same error message and still no disconnect message printed after fixing function name.

Comment: This might sound trivial but can you try introducing `time.sleep(0.1)` just before line `if GPIO.input(10) == GPIO.HIGH:`. Dont forget to `import time`

Comment: Ha, that seems work work...! Could you maybe explain why this fixes it?

Comment: Python tries to execute code under `while` loop as fast as it can, but in turn it might be causing extra load on cpu over the time and eventually lead to memory overflow. This should be the issue in your case.

Comment: @Paandittya Okay, thanks for this!! Does that mean that even now it may cause an issue over longer periods of time? The CPU indicator on the raspberry is now at 0-1% with both the server and the python script running and pushing buttons.

Comment: No. You are fine now. In fact if you feel you can fine tune sleep duration further down and check if cpu load remains within limit of 2-3%.